# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3x^2}{4x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

of $3x^2/4x^2 $

Is it undefined or $6/8$?

If we apply the Hospital rule we get $6/8$, so I think it is $6/8$.

It would be undefined if it were $3x^2/4x^3$.

Comment: Don't need to go to Hospital.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When evaluating limits, remember that the function value at the point is immaterial. What matters is what happens in a "deleted neighborhood" i.e. a neighborhood without the point. So in this case, the function is 3/4 everywhere except at x=0. Hence the limit as x tends to 0 is 3/4. Not undefined just because the function is undefined there.

Answer (score 5):

Note that for all $x\neq 0$:
$$\frac{3x^2}{4x^2} = \frac{3}{4}.
$$
Hence then limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\;\frac{3x^2}{4x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\;\frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{4}.
$$
This of course is the same as $\displaystyle{\frac{6}{8}}$.

The thing is that considering the limit you may assume that $x$ is not equal to zero.

Answer (score 5):

Here again, while in this problem you *CAN* use l'Hopital's rule, there really is *NO need* to use it in this case, and using it doesn't make this limit any easier solve.

We have that for all $x\neq 0$: $\quad \dfrac{3x^2}{4x^2} = \dfrac{3}{4} \left(=\dfrac68\right).$

$$\text{So }\quad \lim_{x\to 0}\;\frac{3x^2}{4x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\;\frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{4}.$$

When taking the limit as $x\to 0$, *all that matters* is what is happening as $x$ *gets VERY VERY close* to $0$, *not* what is happening *AT* $x = 0$.

---

It may very well be that for *some* functions, $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = c$ for some value $c$ *and* that $f(0) = c$, but all that really matters is what happens *very near* to $x = 0$.

Comment: Why this poor man is named frequently, Hospial? :D

Answer (score 1):

It is $\frac34$ everywhere except at $x=0$, for both positive and negative $x$, so $\frac34$ is the limit at $x=0$.

Comment: ...so $\frac34$ is the limit as $x\to 0$, (limit "at" $x$ "=" $0$ may further confuse).